# Site Minder People Picker should work like windows authentication results

Tags: 2010, authentication, claims, sts

I have a custom STS(Site Minder) and windows authentication configured for sharepoint web application. In the people picker for Windows authentication, I can search by **first name**, **last name**, **email id**. But when I login using the Site Minder, I cannot see search results with **first name**, **last name** or **email**. How do i take care of this in Site Minder, so that i get results for fname, lname and email?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default way to search for users when using SAML authentication like with SiteMinder federation as SharePoint has no way to know what kind of directory you are using let alone performing lookups in it.

The solution is to build a custom claims provider that plugs into SharePoint to provide additional services: claims augmentation and claims lookup.

Claims augmentation provides a way for you to add additional claims to the list of claims provided by SiteMinder (typically only the identity claim).

Claims lookup functionality can be developed by specifying the specific search connections & lookup logic needed to connect to your backend directory (typically LDAP) and to list search results in the people picker.

This article gives a good overview on how to build one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699494.aspx

CA also sells a component that does this for you:

http://www.ca.com/us/collateral/product-briefs/na/CA-SiteMinder-Agent-for-SharePoint.aspx

Additionally, there is a good whitepaper on how to setup the federation itself:

http://interopvendoralliance.org/labs/siteminder-federation-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What is this article about

https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20Agent%20for%20SharePoint%202010%2012%205%201-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/idocs/index.htm?toc.htm?1827615.html

Isn't this telling that People Picker should work oob without any other customization?

Comment: "The Claims Provider in the Agent for SharePoint is used for configuring particular claim values to grant permissions to SharePoint resources using the SharePoint people picker. The Claims Provider is packaged as a SharePoint solution (WSP file) with its feature receiver.

The Claims Provider requires Directory Attribute Mappings that you configure using the SiteMinder Administrative UI. The Claims Provider uses these mappings to display the results of your searches in the SharePoint people picker."

Comment: Thanks for you response Danny. Can you please confirm this- If I have SiteMinder ver 12 , SP3 and SP 2010, without developing any custom code, I will be able to integrate SP 2010 with SM and the People Picker will let me search for users in Site Minder claims provider?

Comment: Please dont just post external links. Explain with samples what in that link would help answering the Q and *then* link. External sites tend to die faster than our site, and hence we want to keep info in the site instead of linking externally.